# PHP - exporting data to excel

Tags: php, export, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I have some data that I need to export to excel.  Right now it exports to some other type of file, that I am able to open and read with notepad, but not excel.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"ISBN\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.xls");
        // filename for download    
function output($data){ 

    //print_r($data);
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $data);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';


    $filename = "nonprofitdata" . date_default_timezone_set('Ymd') . ".xls";

        $flag = false;
        foreach($data as $row) {
            if(!$flag) {
                // display field/column names as first row
                echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
                $flag = true;
            }
        array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
        }
        exit;
}
?>
```

How can I update this so that it will export to a file type that Excel can read?

Comment: Try PHPExcel: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: That is where I got this code.

Comment: Write a CSV file with `fputcsv()`, perhaps.

Comment: multiple issues here: 1. `output()` is never called; 2. what is the contents of `$data`? 3. filename is "ISBN" ? missing out file extension? 4. i don't see you using PHPExcel functions 5. last, what is the error shown in MS Excel ?

Comment: Actually, this appears to be a Tab-separated format. Excel will read those if you're clever. There's are any number of  tutorials on the web - try [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OriqzXqLcaw)

Comment: http://@kimberlie-davis You didn't get that code (homebrew csv file writer script) from PHPExcel at all